# How to look for a str/int in a json file?

Tags: c++, json

I have a json full of several entries(magic runes for a game project). I use spirit_json as well, I need a way that in c++ I can get a string from this json. If that's easy enough then I would also like to know how to check the name of whatever magic rune I am searching for this string from.

So as not to confuse say there are 5 runes in the json named, rune 1, rune 2 and so on. How would I in c++ pull a string from one of these runes?

My knowledge of json's is very weak and I have tried reading several topics on this and json_spirit's git hub, but I am still struggling with it. If no one can help with the above request can you at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help!

{
     "Rune_fire1": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 1",
         "damage": 1,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,

```
     "description": "The First Shard of the Fire Rune."
 },


 "Rune_fire2": {
 "level": 1,
     "name": "Fire Rune 2",
     "damage": 2,
     "hp": 0,
     "runecost": 0,
     "defense": 0,
     "negate": 0,
     "evasion": 0,
     "healing": 0,
     "description": "The Second Shard of the Fire Rune."
 },


 "Rune_fire3": {
 "level": 1,
     "name": "Fire Rune 3",
     "damage": 3,
     "hp": 0,
     "runecost": 0,
     "defense": 0,
     "negate": 0,
     "evasion": 0,
     "healing": 0,
     "description": "The Third Shard of the Fire Rune."
 },


 "Rune_fire4": {
 "level": 1,
     "name": "Fire Rune 4",
     "damage": 4,
     "hp": 0,
     "runecost": 0,
     "defense": 0,
     "negate": 0,
     "evasion": 0,
     "healing": 0,
     "description": "The Fourth Shard of the Fire Rune."
 },


 "Rune_fire5": {
 "level": 1,
     "name": "Fire Rune 5",
     "damage": 5,
     "hp": 0,
     "runecost": 0,
     "defense": 0,
     "negate": 0,
     "evasion": 0,
     "healing": 0,
     "description": "The Fifth Shard of the Fire Rune."
 },
```

Comment: I'm guessing your json file has some kind of structure to it? Perhaps a name field? It should be formatted well enough that you know which strings should be interpreted as integers. I just don't think there's enough in your question here for us to go on.

Comment: @NulledPointer The OP is already using a JSON parser.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: I updated the question to include it. How would I go about getting them from c++? I need to search for a specific value from c++